# How do I return to a previous kernel?

Tags: 11.10, kernel, firefox

I downloaded and installed the `3.0.0-21` update to the kernel. It caused several problems including:

1. Firefox not asking for a folder before placing a URL into bookmarks
2. Ubuntu 11.10 not automatically opening to the desktop (I still haven't figuring out a viable work around).

This may be an inability to hibernate and reinstall, but I believe I also had problems after shutdown and booting.

I have tried to learn how to return to the former `3.0.0-19`, but I can't find anything to teach me. I would like to know how to return to the -19 configuration or how to reinstall the -21 configuration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the kernel version wouldn't be responsible for the Firefox issue you've seen.  It is more likely to be due to some other upgrade you did around the same time.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot hold shift as soon as the Mainboard screen goes away to bring up the GRUB menu

select "Previous Version" from the menu
select the last version that worked

report back whether that works for you -- can make it a permanent change or flip back and forth until you can get -21 to work properly

Comment: That worked to get me back to -19, thanks! I then deleted all the -21 files from the boot directory which caused a predictable non-boot condition. Ultimately, the system fixed itself back to the -19 configuration. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it worked for ya